# ibm_db thows invalid connection handle or connection is closed even it is showing connected as true in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I am having my nodejs code where I am using the ibm_db connections to execute the query I call

when I pass the query

```
let result = db2.executeSql(query);
```

it goes to my config file and first check if the connection is closed or not if not closed it execute querySync method but it is giving me an **invalid connection handle or the connection is closed.SQL STATE = S1000**

I checked locally and it is working fine also tried connecting my string with the DB visualizer and it is good not sure what I am doing wrong.

am I doing anything wrong here? after restarting the server it starts working but I cannot restart the server every time.

**does closing the connection using closesync method will remove connection from the pool or it will still stay there? If someone can help to modify the better logic please guide.**

**do I need to add timeout in my pool?**

Comment: How are you keeping your connection alive? It is normal for connections to get stale over time, or get disconnected (for whatever reason) by the Db2-server. It's the job of your code to keep the connection alive, various solutions exist for this purpose.

Comment: actually, I close the connection once it is used and open it when I require it, also reOpenIfClose method will check if the connection is closed or not and if it is closed it will reopen.

Comment: Things are rarely what they seem on the surface, and assumptions are often incorrect. Which version of node are you running?  Which operating sysstem?  What is the FULL text of the exception? Which Db2 driver __version__ are you using (i.e. the output of the `db2level` command)?  Are you able to run a cli trace to see what is actually happening under the covers?

Comment: Is `connected` an official attribute? From where is the value? As the message states, it could be an invalid (stale) handle.

Comment: I consoled the connection and it is showing the object which i added in the question